# Flutter iOS "replacing existing signature" "permission denied" error. Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, flutter, dependencies, code-signing, permission-denied

I was working on this flutter project mainly for ios deployment for about 4 months and we had to revisit the project to make some changes. It was working fine. I had to add firebase_crashlytics to the project. So when I added it, an error popped up saying:

```
The current Flutter SDK version is 1.9.1+hotfix.4.

Because vitalsmobile depends on firebase_crashlytics >=0.1.2 which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.9.1+hotfix.5 <2.0.0, version solving failed.

pub get failed
```

So I reverted and tried compiling for ios simulator to check if everything was working fine and iOS threw this error:

```
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/ag32547/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ehsppxamrnwyncckggzztyutcqwg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-62580339D8295FD31996B914.sh (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    cd /Users/ag32547/Documents/GitHub/vitalsmobileboilerplate/ios
    /bin/sh -c /Users/ag32547/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ehsppxamrnwyncckggzztyutcqwg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-62580339D8295FD31996B914.sh

mkdir -p /Users/ag32547/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ehsppxamrnwyncckggzztyutcqwg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/ag32547/Documents/GitHub/vitalsmobileboilerplate/ios/Pods/../Flutter/Flutter.framework" "/Users/ag32547/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ehsppxamrnwyncckggzztyutcqwg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... done
Flutter.framework/
Flutter.framework/Flutter
Flutter.framework/Info.plist
Flutter.framework/icudtl.dat
Flutter.framework/_CodeSignature/
Flutter.framework/_CodeSignature/CodeResources

sent 94440040 bytes  received 120 bytes  62960106.67 bytes/sec
total size is 94428117  speedup is 1.00
Stripped /Users/ag32547/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ehsppxamrnwyncckggzztyutcqwg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter of architectures: armv7 arm64
Code Signing /Users/ag32547/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ehsppxamrnwyncckggzztyutcqwg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework with Identity -
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign -  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/ag32547/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ehsppxamrnwyncckggzztyutcqwg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework'
/Users/ag32547/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ehsppxamrnwyncckggzztyutcqwg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework: replacing existing signature
/Users/ag32547/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ehsppxamrnwyncckggzztyutcqwg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework: Permission denied
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I have no idea where I went wrong.

All I modified after taking the old project were:

1. Changed the team and bundle identifier to a developer certified license to distribute the app.
2. Updated some dependencies in flutter pubspec.yaml

If more information is needed I'm ready to provide it.
Any insight into this will be really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occured when I was setting up the firebase in the app. I changed the app in xcode editor while that was not necessary. Flutter takes care of it for you. So when running the commands it is important to add the commands in fluter.

I also deleted the Podfile.lock, pod files and .xcworkspace and ran pod install and upgrade from the terminal. And I also ran "flutter clean" and recompiled.